# Is there a name for color coding B-Mode ultrasound?

Tags: radiology

Recently i saw an ultrasound device which instead of displaying the image on a grayscale displayed the image on a color gradient scale from yellow (on the bright end) over red towards black (on the dark end). Is there any name for the approach of displaying B-Mode on a color scale?
All my attempts at searching for this lead me to information on color coded CW-Doppler sonography which is explicitly not what i am looking for.

Comment: Do you know the make and model of the device? The product information for it might give a name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I know what you mean - they're different **color maps** in lieu of the usual grayscale. I've very rarely seen them used by physicians and it is impossible to find screenshots online (sadly these days I don't have access to an ultrasound station).

From the GE Vivid 7/Vivid 7 PRO [User's Manual](http://medicalstore.hu/hasznalt_ultrahangok/GE%20VIVID%207/GE%20Vivid%207%20ultrasound%20-%20Users%20guide.pdf):

[image: Page 93]

Same manual, page 94

> Color maps Displays a color map menu to optimize the greyscale
> presentation. The menu enables an option from a list of nonlinear
> gray-curves or different 2D-colorized curves to be selected.